# how to call a jquery function on image click

Tags: jquery

I've an image in my JSP page. I need to call the jquery function on click of that image. Please help me !!

JSP page look like,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="image" id="closeAuction" value="Close Auction" align="right" src="images/close_auction.png" onclick="return endAuction();" disabled / > 
    </body>
</html>
```

My jquery function inside the script tag looks like,

```
<script src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {     
        $('#closeAuction').click(function() {
            location.reload();     
        });    
    });
</script>
```

But the script doesn't work!! Could anyone help on calling a function on image click..

Comment: You're missing a closing quote in your selector.

Comment: Any code contained in a `<script>` tag with a `src` attribute will be ignored

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a quote.. `$('#closeAuction')`

Change `$('#closeAuction)` to `$('#closeAuction')`

Also you need to put it in a new script

```
<script src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> //Added new `<script>` tag
   $(document).ready(function() {
     //added missing-v quotes 
     $('#closeAuction').click(function() {
        location.reload();     
     });    
   });    
</script>
```

Comment: sorry i missed the quote while pasting it here, quotes are giving properly in the application. Even though it isn't working !!

Comment: @Varsha You need to include it in a new script tags.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing quote and you also need to place your code in it's own script block. Try this:

```
<script src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {     
        $('#closeAuction').click(function() { // <-- note closing quote on selector.
            location.reload();     
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Is there a specific reason you're using such an outdated version of jQuery? You should try upgrading to 1.8.3.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$('#closeAuction)` with `$('#closeAuction')`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put code inside a `script` tag that is used to load an external resource.

```
<script src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('#closeAuction').click(function() {
        location.reload();     
    });    
});
</script>
```